# If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, prove $f\circ g$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

> Suppose that $(X,T)$, $(Y,U)$ and $(Z,V)$ are three topological spaces and that
>   $g\colon X\to Y$ and $h\colon Y \to  Z$ are continuous. Prove that $h\circ g\colon X \to Z$ is a continuous function between $(X,T)$ and $(Z,V)$.

This is a question in a past paper I am attempting however I do not have any solutions and need to check if my attempt is correct:

Let $A\subseteq Z$ be open, then

$$g^{-1}(h^{-1}(A))=(h\circ g)^{-1}A$$

is open in $X$, hence $h\circ g$ is continuous.

I think I am missing out some steps somewhere?

Comment: You might want to add a step where you look at $h^{-1}(A)$ and conclude something about that before pulling it further back via $g$.

Comment: What does $(h \circ g)^({-1})V$ mean? Isn't $V$ the topology?

Comment: Nope, not really. You could say explicitly that $h^{-1}(A)=B$ is open by the continuity of $h$ and $g^{-1}(B)$ is open by the continuity of $g$.

Comment: Thanks, guys! Sorry @AlexP., it was a typo, fixed it now!

Comment: @Nicky It looks good now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really wanted to be cautious, you'd point out that $h^{-1}(A)$ is open in $Y$, and so $$g^{-1}(h^{-1}(A))=(h\circ g)^{-1}(A)$$ is open in $X$. It's pretty straightforward, though.

Answer (score 2):

your answer is not complete you need to say that
since $A$ is open and h is continuous then $h^{-1}(A)$ is open 
also since $g$ is continuous and $h^{-1}(A)$ is open then $g^{-1}(h^{-1}(A))$ is open
so $h\circ g$ is continuous